# Tag suggestion: natural history

Tags: feature-request, tags, tagging

I have a question about my History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [What are other ancient encyclopaedic texts like Pliny's “Naturalis Historia” that were available to medieval people?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6394/what-are-other-ancient-encyclopaedic-texts-like-plinys-naturalis-historia-tha)

This is also of general interest, but my question is a good example of a inquiry about a natural history topic. Natural history is not congruent with biology. Therefore it seems important to have the ability to tag posts with natural history as well.